# How to write log message with trace command in tcl?

Tags: tcl

So I have these sample code:

```
package require logger
set logger [logger::init someservice]
proc second {} {}
proc first {} {second}
${logger}::trace on
${logger}::trace add first second
puts "monitored procesured are: [${logger}::trace status]"
first
${logger}::delete
```

I got the following result after running the code :

```
[Wed Mar 14 11:44:11 EDT 2018] [someservice] [trace] 'enter {proc ::first 
level 1 script {} caller {} procargs {}}'
[Wed Mar 14 11:44:11 EDT 2018] [someservice] [trace] 'enter {proc ::second 
level 2 script {} caller ::first procargs {}}'
[Wed Mar 14 11:44:11 EDT 2018] [someservice] [trace] 'leave {proc ::second 
level 2 script {} caller ::first status ok result {}}'
[Wed Mar 14 11:44:11 EDT 2018] [someservice] [trace] 'leave {proc ::first 
level 1 script {} caller {} status ok result {}}'
```

I am trying to figure out how to use logger to write the result to a text file by setting up a filehandler. I tried to put "${::filehandler}" in the middle of the code, but it only printed out "first" in the text file. How should I type the command to print out the working process in another log file?

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [logger](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/log/logger.html) documentation, especially the section on [logproc](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/log/logger.html#24):

```
proc log2file {lvl txt} { 
   # handle output to file handle
}

set log [::logger::init example]
${log}::logproc trace log2file
```

Comment: Also look at `logger::utils` and `logger::appender` it has a few helpers to define and apply logprocs.